# asp.net jquery token input not working while running in debugger mode

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using Jquery tokenizer as like facebook using the following plugin

http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

which works great.
Only the issue is, when I run it from the Visual Studio, the default URL looks like http://localhost:1234, the auto complete not works when the http contains the port number, it works fine when we publish and see without port number.

Here my question is, can we make it work with port number or can we run the visual studio with debugger without port number.

The following doesn't work.

```
<input type="text" id="Text1" name="blah" />
        <input type="button" value="Submit" />
         <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#Text1").tokenInput("http://localhost:1299/SVSS/multisuggest.aspx", {
                theme: "facebook"
            });
        });
        </script>
```

It works fine with following code

```
 <input type="text" id="Text2" name="blah" />
        <input type="button" value="Submit" />
         <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#Text2").tokenInput("http://system2/college/multisuggest.aspx", {
                theme: "facebook"
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It treating as cross domain when you use ports. Just change the following code in .js file

```
 // Add the following line
         settings.crossDomain = false;
     // Before the following code
        if(settings.crossDomain === undefined) {
            if(url.indexOf("://") === -1) {
                settings.crossDomain = false;
            } else {
                settings.crossDomain = (location.href.split(/\/+/g)[1] !== url.split(/\/+/g)[1]);
            }
        }
```